# SPC to WAV command-line

Tags: command-line, format-conversion

For example, these types of .SPC files:
[random SPC and WAV folder](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B87K-9VTscocQllJTUhUQjZoSlk)

I don't want it to bring a window in the foreground, just an invisible process that will convert an SPC to a WAV.

```
executable foo/bar/input.spc bar/foo/output.wav
```

I'm using this in a command-line Java application, so a Java solution would be appreciated if possible. (I can use `ProcessBuilder` to run the executable if not.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How convenient! FFMPEG can read and convert SPC files!

```
ffmpeg -i night1.spc -acodec pcm_u8 -ar 44100 night1.wav
```

Now, this command will convert your file pretty cleanly, and will spit out a nice `.wav` file (be sure to replace `night1.spc` and `night1.wav` with whatever you want the filenames to be).

Unfortunately, this does not end the story in the slightest. After running the above command for a while, I got the following result:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kazwolfe kazwolfe 297M Mar 28 02:05 night1.wav
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kazwolfe kazwolfe  65K Mar 28 02:01 night1.spc
```

This can't be right... let's pop open the file in Audacity and see what's going on:

[image]

In short, SPC files don't have a length defined in them. While there [is a mention of length in the spec](http://vspcplay.raphnet.net/spc_file_format.txt), it seems to be often ignored, and actually *is* ignored in the files uploaded to your Google Drive.

SPC files, as ripped from the SNES (in its original format) were meant to loop pretty much forever. As such, when they're played (or converted in this case), they're going to also loop forever.

So, we need to manually pass in the length (and possibly offset) to `ffmpeg`. Fortunately, the program comes with a cool little command line argument called `-t <time>`. Using this, we can specify how much audio we want to convert.

Similarly, if the file has an offset, we can use the `-ss <time>` argument to specify how far from the beginning we want to clip.

Therefore, assuming a 45 second file with an offset of 5 seconds, the command we need to run is:

```
ffmpeg -i night1.spc -t 00:00:45 -ss 00:00:05 -acodec pcm_u8 -ar 44100 night1.wav
```

Comment: Any way we can get the time of a loop from the SPC?

Comment: Besides it being encoded in the ID666 tags, I can't see anything other than going in and manually reading the file. I'm sure this can be programmatically done (e.g. you can see how large the data block of the file is, and then compute approximately how long the loop is that way), but I have been able to find no resources for how to do that. If your SPC files *did* have sound data, it would be stored in the highlighted data block and be readable by vSNES or any other memory editor ([see picture](http://imgur.com/rA5FZ93)).

Comment: SPC700 plays these for two loops and then fades over 5 seconds. Is there a way to specify _that_? @KazWolfe

Comment: @moo_we_all_do If you know the loop length time, sure. As for fade, I think FFMPEG has an option for that. See `man ffmpeg`, as I'm honestly not sure what said option is.

Comment: Nice! I'll definitely be using this. (Sorry for more questions but) is there any way to stream this with sedmelluq/lavaplayer and Discord4Java? I guess if I stream it I can see when it hits the end of a loop?

Comment: So does this mean 1151 seconds? http://imgur.com/a/RcxjH Also, what 
do you mean by "offset?" The `/` and `$` in AMK? @KazWolfe

Comment: @moo_we_all_do By offset, I mean if the loop starts at some time that is non-zero (which may be the case). Most files don't have this.  Also, in your example, it seems to be 115 seconds with a 10 second fade-out. See the [ID666 spec](http://www.alpha-ii.com/Info/SPCFormat.txt) for text, which is what your file is. We can also double-check this. Temmie Village's song in-game is 57 seconds. That's 114 for two loops, which is close enough to 115. Especially if the person who made the SPC wanted a tiny delay between loops.